the .js file is not connected, but the .css is connected
I am writing a training project: client-server on Node JS vanilla js.  using Vite.js
is loaded when the server and client are started index.html which downloads the app.js, which is already loading the rest of the pages. The problem is that the js files connected on other pages are not connected.
That is, if I connect the rest of the js files on the page index.html they work, but not the document.getElementById does not work, since other html has not loaded yet.
This is my server:
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import { router } from './router/index.js'
import { connectToDatabase } from './db/index.js'
import { success, error, info } from './utils/chalk.js'
import socketController from './socket/socket.js'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import http from 'http'
import 'dotenv/config'
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);


// creating express app/server
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('${path.join(__dirname, "../client/index.html")}');
});

// enabling application/json headers
app.use(express.json()) 
// enabling cors policy
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN_URI,
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
}))

// http://localhost:5000
app.use('/api/flights', router.flightRouter)
app.use('/api/passengers', router.passengerRouter)
app.use('/api/airports', router.airportRouter)
app.use('/api/planes', router.planeRouter)
app.use('/api/admins', router.adminRouter)


// socket io connetions
io.on('connection', socketController)


// Connecting to the database
connectToDatabase()
.then(() => console.log(success("[database] [success] Connected to database")))
.catch(() => console.log(error("[database] [error] Doesn't connected to database")))


// starting up the server
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(success(`[server] [success] Server has been started... 
                        \n[server] [success] URL: http://localhost:${port}`))
})

This is index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>URTK Airport Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/index.css">
    <script type="module" src="src/app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

This is app.js
import axios from 'axios';

async function loadPageWithAxios(href) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(href);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при загрузке страницы:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// renderApp.js
import AuthPage from './pages/AuthPage/AuthPage.html';

function renderApp() {
    const isAuthorized = !!localStorage.getItem('token') &&
        !!localStorage.getItem('fullName') &&
        !!localStorage.getItem('admin-type');

    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

    let routing;
    if (!isAuthorized) {
        loadPageWithAxios('src/test.html')
            .then(html => {
                rootElement.innerHTML = html;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Ошибка при загрузке страницы:', error);
            });
    } else {
        loadPageWithAxios(AuthPage)
            .then(html => {
                rootElement.innerHTML = html;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Ошибка при загрузке страницы:', error);
            });
    }
}

window.onload = renderApp;

this is AuthPage.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Вход</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/AuthPage.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/public/js/AuthPage.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="auth">
        <div class="auth__container" id="authContainer">
            <div class="auth__container__header">
                <div class="header__company-logo">URTK Airport</div>
                <div class="header__container-name">Вход</div>
            </div>

            <form class='auth__form' id="authForm">
                <div class="auth__form__item">
                    <div class="item__title">Ваше ФИО</div>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        class="item__input"
                        id="fullNameInput"
                        placeholder='Иванов Иван Иванович'
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="auth__form__item">
                    <div class="item__title">Ваш пароль</div>
                    <input 
                        type="password" 
                        class="item__input"
                        id="passwordInput"
                        placeholder='Пароль' 
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="auth__form__item">
                    <div class="item__title">Секретное слово</div>
                    <input 
                        type="password" 
                        class="item__input"
                        id="secretWordInput"
                        placeholder='Секретное слово'
                    />
                </div>

                <button 
                    class='send-data-button' 
                    type='button'
                    id="submitButton"
                >Войти</button>
            </form>

            <div id="loadingSpinner" class="hidden">Loading...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I connected static files in all ways.
I tried to remove Vite from the client.
Nothing helped

What do you mean by "not connected"? Is it not loaded? Do you have any errors in the developer tools of your browser?

@derpirscher , there is no AuthPage.js in the browser's SOURCES panel, but there is a .css file

Can you please share with us a screenshot of your network tab under the developer tools on your browser?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not relate to your problem, but the term "vanilla js" is normally only used if you just write JS code using the native APIs provided by the environment the code runs in without the usage of any other 3rd party libraries and/or toolchains.


It might be caused by the incorrect import usage.
